# Selenium on Docker: Testing a Docker Image within the same `docker-compose` file

Tags: scala, selenium, docker-compose, selenium-docker

Scenario:

- Docker Image that runs my app on `localhost:9000`
- Docker Images with the Selenium Webdriver
- Selenium tests that I want to run against.

I started from this [SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium)

Docker Compose:

```
version: "3.1"
services:    

  my-app:
    image: pame/play-binding-form-server
    networks:
      - mynet
    ...
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"

  chrome-webdriver:
    image: selenium/standalone-chrome:3.141.59-europium
    networks:
      - mynet
    volumes:
      - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
    ports:
      - "4444:4444"
    depends_on:
      - my-app

networks:
  mynet:
```

`docker ps`:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                          COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                              NAMES
53ac65c2babd        selenium/standalone-chrome:3.141.59-europium   "/opt/bin/entry_poin…"   13 minutes ago      Up 13 minutes       0.0.0.0:4444->4444/tcp             e2e_chrome-webdriver_1
fc0ca2af3148        pame/play-binding-form-server                  "/pme123/conf/docker…"   17 minutes ago      Up 17 minutes       0.0.0.0:9000->9000/tcp, 9443/tcp   pme123-forms
d
```

My test looks like:

```
  import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities
  import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver

  val driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"),
    DesiredCapabilities.chrome())
  driver.get("http://localhost:9000/")
```

This returns a HTML Page:

[image: This site can’t be reached]

I tried different versions, with no success.

When running the `webdriver` locally everything works.

Is this scenario not possible or do I miss something?

Comment: @Siyu - thanks That WORKED! If you create an answer - I can accept it. I still struggle a bit to understand why `http://localhost:4444/wd/hub` then works - and it does not need the hostname, like `http://chrome-webdriver:4444/wd/hub`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a very classic question.

Since `my-app` and `chrome-webdriver` are on two **separate** containers, `chrome-webdrive` can't reach `my-app` on **its** localhost(127.0.0.1).

Keep in mind that one of docker's functions is to isolate running environments with the concept of container. That is, `localhost` on your host machine is not the same as the one of a container, and `localhost` on container A is not the same as the one on container B, they all have their own localhost.

To connect two containers *within the same network*, just use their container name or service name as the host name.

In your case `driver.get("http://my-app:9000/")`.